# Comparing dates from PocketQuery

Tags: velocity, confluence

I'm trying to create a simple program that takes a date and marks it as red, green or yellow depending how far from say "today()" it is.

I'm using PocketQuery http://www.scandio.de/en/atlassian-en/plugins/pocketquery
That I use to get a log time from an Oracle database, the query loads fine and I have a nice little $result list.

This date

Below I used the example template I found in the PocketQuery Doc that I use as a first step in getting my script to work. Just to do a simple datetime compare. The variable LOG_TIME is in datetime format.

This script loops through the result and does X for each row.

I've tested the $dateFormatter.getCurrentDateTime() and it outputs the correct time. 
So it must be something with the reading of the result I think.

The next step would be to get the compare even more finegrained, say check if the LOG_TIME is say...30 min from a set date and color that yellow but first step would be to get the compare working.

```
<style>
.high { background: red; }
.low { background: yellow; }
</style>

<table class="pocketquery-table confluenceTable">


<tr>
#foreach ($column in $columns)
 <th>$!column</th>
#end
</tr>

 #foreach ($row in $result)
   <tr class="#if($row.LOG_TIME < $dateFormatter.getCurrentDate())high#{elseif}     ($row.LOG_TIME > $dateFormatter.getCurrentDateTime())low#end">
  #foreach ($column in $row)

    <td>$!column</td>
#end
 </tr>
</table>
```

TLDR:

- How do I compare a date I got from pocket query to a date I get from Velocity (dateFormat, date, whatever)?

Comment: Hi Remb! Could you ask your question at Atlassian Answers: https://answers.atlassian.com/ using the label "addon-de.scandio.confluence.plugins.pocketquer"? There is active frequent communication on PocketQuery topics and it would be nice to have those questions at one place.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update you guys on my progress.
    I've got a code working somewhat closely to what I want.

```
   <style>
    .high { background: red; font-weight: bold;}
    .low { background: greenyellow; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>

     ##create instance of calender
     #set($todayAtEight = $calendar.getInstance())
     ##set time, todo..check if there is a better way of doing this...
     $todayAtEight.set(15, 10)
     $todayAtEight.set(12, 46)
     $todayAtEight.set(13, 5)
     $todayAtEight.getTime()
     <br/>
     <table>
     ##loop result
     #foreach ($row in $result)
     ##save parameter rowdate

     #set($rowDate = $calendar.getInstance())
     $rowDate.setTime($row.LOGG_TID)
     #if($todayAtEight.before($rowDate))
      <tr class="low">
      #else
      <tr class="high">
       #end
         <td> 
          $dateFormatter.formatGivenString("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", $row.LOGG_TID)
         </td>
         <td>
     $row.DVH_AREA
     </td>
     </tr>
    #end
    </table>
```